# Cookies: why aren't they big enough? what is there to store that a cookie can't contain?

Tags: javascript, cookies, size, local-storage

I am inexperienced and don't understand why you would need more than the size limit of a cookie. Local Storage holds around 5mb, what could someone possibly put into a local storage value that's that big? I really just want to understand, could someone give me examples of what people store that's more than just a few words or a large link?

Comment: ["640 K ought to be enough for anybody."
-- Bill Gates, 1981](http://www.slothmud.org/~hayward/mic_humor/mic_quotes.html)

Comment: [HTTP cookies](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20020803110822/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html) were first specified in 1994 ([IETF specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2109) dated 1997); [specification of Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) started in 2009 and is still in progress.

Comment: @Sean [That wasn't actually said by Bill Gates](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bill_Gates).

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: [Bill Gates never stated that.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bill_Gates#Misattributed)

Comment: @alex, Gumba I know (and I should've said so). It just sounds a lot better like that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh it's very simple. If you design a decently-sized application and for some reason decide you would like to store the state of the application in the client, then 4kb are not a lot.

Examples:

- A tree-shaped menu and you want to store each menu item's collapsed/expanded state
- A search form where you want to have default values for all your selects
- Lots of other things

That's why, in the end, you simply don't store those things in a cookie (apart from security reasons, of course)

Comment: but each cookie has 4kb, right? so if I wanted to store the state of an app, you just store it all in different cookies, isn't that how people usually do it?

Comment: On some browsers, cookies may be bigger than 4kb. But you can't expect that. See **Gumbo**'s answer for a link to the IETF specification. Of course you can always store several cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Local storage can be used for offline use, cookies cannot. also cookies get sent to the server with ever request.. you wouldn't want to be sending 5MBs with every HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Any web application targeting a mobile device that the designer wants to be usable when the mobile device is not connected to the internet has lots of storage needs. Think email, RSS, documents to begin with :)

A specific app that I love that does this is http://www.readability.com/

Answer (score 0):

These two storage solutions are not quite comparable as they work differently: Although in both cases the data is store on the client side, a Cookie is sent along with every request while Web Storage in only for local use.

But besides that: [HTTP cookies](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20020803110822/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html) were first drafted in 1994 ([IETF specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) dated 1997); [specification of Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) started in 2009 and is still in progress. Just think of how the Web evolved in those 15 years.